# Crawling is not limited to the content sources in Start Addresses

Tags: search, crawl

I have a content source for my web application which points
to some document libraries.
So for example in amy content source I have the following Start Addresses:

```
http://myhost:8001/mysusite/doc1
http://myhost:8001/mysusite/doc2
http://myhost:8001/mysusite/doc3
```

When I start full crawling I see that the crawling is not limited to my content source but apparently extends to all the web application.
In the crawl log I see that even user sites are crawled.
Ex.

```
http://myhost:8001/personal/user1
http://myhost:8001/personal/user1/Documents
...
```

Do I need to set anything more to restrict the crawling to only the document libraries I want?

**EDIT:**
This is what I have set for my content source

[image]

Comment: Instead of "Web Sites", select "SharePoint Sites" and your Crawl settings further down will change to the image in my answer. I'll see if we can restrict it to only libraries... hang on :)

Comment: Under crawling you can select file types to be crawled. But remember this is a global setting for the entire farm. Maybe a far too wide setting?

Comment: What I don't understand is why the crawling includes contents from resources that are not in my content sources. Can you answer this?

Comment: Yes: Select "SharePoint Sites" instead of "Web Sites" to start with. Then select to "Only crawl the site collection of each start address". When done, perform index reset and do a full crawl and see in the crawl log that everything works as expected. After that you can continue to restrict file types in crawl rules...

Comment: I've tried that. It still fetches content from other sites.Sorry, the question but did you try it yourself and were able to limit the crawling to the content libraries only?

Comment: Besides, you wrote that you can answer but you didn't do it.

Comment: Sorry for trying to help you. I'll stop now.

Comment: oh come on don't be touchy...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are. Probably the content source you have has the crawl setting set to "Crawl everything under the hostname for each start address". In your case this means `http://myhost:8001/` which includes your personal sites.

Instead select the other option "Only crawl the Site Collection of each start address".

[image]

This may not be changeble. If not create a new content source (with your current URL:s) and delete the old one.

When done, make an index reset and start a full crawl (outside office hours).

## Excluding content to be crawled

Go to the Crawl Rules page in your SSA and create an exclusion rule that matches all aspx-files, like this `http://myhost:8001/*.aspx`. This means that all aspx-pages will be exluded from crawling. Do this with all other file types you don't want to crawl (check the File Types link of which you want to exclude ~60 file types).

Check that this works using the test URL input box above the Add Rule button to see that it actually works.

Reference: [Manage crawl rules in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219686.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to crawl libraries only. Please check my edit. Is my setting correct?

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't answer my question. It's not a question of removing file types from the crawling. My problem is that I restricted the crawling in content sources to a few libraries. Still, the crawling includes the whole farm. And this of course is not acceptable.

Comment: I think there may be a bit of confusion here.  What SharePoint 'crawls' and what it exposes as query results in a particular circumstance are two separate processes.   "Generally", in a SharePoint farm, all the content is crawled so it's in the index, then you filter it with Result Sources, Query Rules and item security at the appropriate level.  It's easily doable to crawl your entire content source, then create a Result Source 5hat only shows certain document libraries.

Comment: From my understanding you can crawl just part of the content (and not all) with the Content sources (not result sources)

Comment: You can.  It really depends on what your overall content sources look like.  You can't have overlapping rules so you "may" run into that issue by going too fine-grained.